# How can I get around a "Can not verify rule set jar" error when accessing a website

Tags: windows, java, certificate, website

I keep encountering the following error when attempting to visit a website. What would be the best way to get around it? From what I've read online it looks like the recommendation is to import this site's cert into my trusted certificates store, but I'm not sure how to go about obtaining this certificate as this isn't a website that I manage.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can rename the file:

- C:\windows\sun\java\Deployment\DeploymentRuleSet.jar

to what ever else and then you get rid of this error.

How safe it is I have no clue, but it works.